# react-dom.development.js?61bb:530 Warning: Prop className did not match

Tags: material-ui

react-dom.development.js?61bb:530 Warning: Prop `className` did not match.

Server: "MuiTypography-root makeStyles-root-32 makeStyles-root-47 makeStyles-darkest-27 makeStyles-bodySmall-43 makeStyles-noTextTransform-41 MuiTypography-body1" 
Client: "MuiTypography-root makeStyles-root-32 makeStyles-root-48 makeStyles-darkest-27 makeStyles-bodySmall-43 makeStyles-noTextTransform-41 MuiTypography-body1"

I have tried the following so far to no avail:

- configured runtime chunk in webpack, as we are code splitting at the route level,

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'app',
    },
  },
```

- verified there is only one version of material-ui, the latest, 4.9.3
- node environment is the same for both client and server
- tried wrapping both the client and app in stylesprovider with a fresh createGenerateClassName:

server:

```
const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();

      const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
        productionPrefix: 'tock',
      });

      const html = ReactDomServer.renderToString(
        sheets.collect(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={routerContext}>
              <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Application />
              </StylesProvider>
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>
        )
      );
```

as well as ensuring that new `ServerStyleSheets` is created on every requuest.

client:

```
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    productionPrefix: 'tock',
  });
  try {
    (fullRender ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate)(
      <StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={tockHistory}>
            <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
              <Routes />
            </StylesProvider>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </StrictMode>,
      document.querySelector('#Root')
    );
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
```

followed the reference implementation:
https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/

this seems to only be happening in development mode. If I bundle for production and run the app, it's working.

worked through:
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#my-app-doesnt-render-correctly-on-the-server

specifically, I was interested in this:
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#react-class-name-hydration-mismatch

Node: v13.8.0
Webpack: 4.41.6
Material-ui: 4.9.3

the component where we started seeing this issue, interestingly, uses some prop based styles:

```
export const useTypographyStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginBottom: ({ mb, paragraph }: TypographyProps) =>
      paragraph ? theme.spacing(2) : theme.spacing(mb ?? 0),
  },
```

which I notice generates 2 strings for the classes in the hook.

```
root: "makeStyles-root-32 makeStyles-root-232"
```

is what I get when I log the result of:

```
const classes = useTypographyStyles({ mb, paragraph });
```

but if I do a regular style there with just a value, I do not get the issue.

Comment: also posted on material-ui github:https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19772

Comment: I tried it with the combination of `withStyles` and `createStyles` as well, and still have the same result.

Comment: Also more information is that i'm using webpack to compile the backend as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't much help but changing the specific error triggering className worked for me. I had a class called EmojiWrapper and it was giving the error of client/server difference. So I renamed it and the problem went away. I think it has something to do with caching.

Comment: For future reference, if you are using Nextjs, there is a big chance it's related to caching. Restart your dev server and the error should go away.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm also facing this issue while using next. But only on dev. Once deployed using next start, this is not encountered.